# How much is the king worth material-wise?

Tags: kings, point-value

In chess classes, I have been told either that king is worth an infinite amount of points or 10 points. What is the actual material-worth of the king piece?

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! The answer in the linked question also discusses the 'tactical' strength of the king and gives it a point value.

Comment: The question is meaningless. What do you mean with "worth"?

Comment: Both sides always have 1 king, so there's usually no situations where the value of the king matters.

Comment: The value of the King is infinite, but its power is about that of a minor piece.